# How to implement a priority queue using two queues

Tags: queue, priority-queue

In a interview question I was asked to **implement a priority queue using queues**,

After the interview I googled it and found that it can be implemented using two queues, but I did not find how..

Please can anybody explain me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where did you find that statement? Please post a link.

Comment: What methods/accessors are available on a "queue", what is needed on a priority queue? What efficiency was required for which operations? There are so many possible implementations…

Comment: @Bergi why do you think that its from a site, I clearly mentioned that I was asked this in an interview, I am a B tech student, am currently I am going through interviews for my internship.
You can google the question if you prefer.

Comment: @Bergi what do you mean "What methods/accessors are available on a 'queue' ", the ones that are available in a normal queue, look bro if you dont wanna help there is no need to, there are others who can answer this question.

Comment: I just asked for the page where you "*found that it can be implemented using two queues*", not the page that gave you the assignment. My second question was about what you think is a typical, "normal" queue. Does it only have push/shift operations?

Comment: Those were good questions. You stated you found on google it could be done. @Bergi just asked where. As well, not all queue's have the same operations. A enqueue, of course, and a pop. Does it have a peek? Makes quite a difference on efficiency.

Comment: @Bergi when i searched for "**how to implement priority queue using queues**" google automatically showed the suggestion "**how to implement priority queue using two  queues**"

Comment: @Noctua see as the question was asked in a interview for internship I dont bother about the efficiency, I just need a simple solution that I could have answered there. I dont want to use it in production or something.

Comment: Is 2 queues really necessary ?

Comment: @NagendraYadav: Still, more chance of a job when it's more efficient, I think ;-)

Comment: @whoknows no not at all, but the solution should make some sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A basic solution

Use two queues

1. first one includes all the **elements** only
2. second one includes the **respective priority** of the element in the first queue.

   - **Insertion** : for every element insert the value in first queue, and its priority in second
                                                   Time Complexity **O(1)**
   - **Get the top element** : search the second queue for highest priority, the respective element in the first queue is the top element of the priority queue
                                                   Time Complexity **O(n)**

Comment: why can't I use the single queue and insert both value and priority as structure in queue. So that I can fetch data using single queue instead of two queue

Comment: This not only takes O(n) time to get the top element, it also uses an extra O(n) space.

Comment: There is no point to this solution. Why is it accepted??

Answer (score 9):

The main advantage of using a priority queue is that we can get min/max at a constant time. So it is the first criteria that should be met. We are considering key values only.
We can create a prioity queue using two Queues name them q1 and q2
if the input element is larger than top of q1 then append it to q1 else

if the input is smaller than top of q1 then repeat

remove element from q1 and insert to q2 till top is greater than that element

now add the element

now insert the remaining elements to the q2

```
so like input is 2 4 1 5 3
pass 1)
q1-> 2 
q2->  
pass 2)
q1-> 2 4
q2->
pass 3)
q1-> 
q2->1 2 4 // since 1 is less than top of q1 add it to q2 and then pop all the elements to q2
pass 4)
q1-> 
q2-> 1 2 4 5 //add it to q2 since it is larger than all the elements
pass 5)
q1-> 1 2 3 4 5//pop the elements smaller than q3 and then add the element and append the        remaining

q2->
```

Answer (score 1):

There are of course several options. The first one I can think of uses only 1 queue, but assumes you do know the size of the queue.

Complexities are not very well, insertion would be linear, popping is constant.

Below is the pseudo python 3 code.

```
class PriorityQueue(Queue):

    def insert(self, item):
        for i in range(self.size):
            next = self.pop()
            if next < item:
                self.enqueue(next)
            else:
                self.enqueue(item)
                self.enqueue(next)
                break
        for i in range(i, self.size):
            self.enqueue(self.pop())

    def pop(self):
        return self.pop()
```

I've used the name 'self.pop' for taking the first item from the original queue. The 'self.enqueue' puts an item on the end of the original queue.

How it works: The insertion takes all the smaller items from the queue, and puts them at the end. When the new item is the smallest, put that one at the end. After that, just put the remainder of the items at the end.

Note that I did not put the details in my code, like the case wherein the queue is empty, possibly full, ... This code will not work, but it should convey the idea.

A working solution in python 3:

```
from queue import Queue

class PriorityQueue(Queue):

    def insert(self, item):
        if self.empty():
            self.put(item)
            return
        i = 0
        size = self.qsize()
        n = self.get()
        while item > n and i < size:
            self.put(n)
            n = self.get()
            i += 1
        if i == size:
            self.put(item)
            self.put(n)
            for i in range(size): self.put(self.get())
        else:
            self.put(item)
            self.put(n)
            for j in range(i + 1, size): self.put(self.get())
```

Comment: any solution using two queues??

Comment: Can't think of any faster than linear implementation using 2 queues.

Answer (score -1):

**This is some question I came across.
Implementing a maxQueue using 2 Queues**

Dequeue time complexity - O(1)
Enqueue time complexity - O(n)

Code in java

public class _01_MaximumQueue {

```
/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

public class QueueWithMax<T extends Comparable<T>> {
    Queue<T> enteries = new ArrayDeque<T>();
    Deque<T> candidatesForMax = new ArrayDeque<T>();

    public void enqueue(T x) {

        enteries.add(x);

        if (candidatesForMax.peekLast().compareTo(x) < 0) {
            candidatesForMax.removeLast();
        }
        candidatesForMax.addLast(x);

    }

    public T dequeue() {

        if (!enteries.isEmpty()) {
            T result = enteries.remove();
            if (candidatesForMax.peekFirst().equals(result)) {
                candidatesForMax.removeFirst();
            }
            return result;
        }

        throw new IllegalStateException("called Degueue() on empty Queue");
    }

    public T max() {
        if (!candidatesForMax.isEmpty()) {
            return candidatesForMax.peekFirst();
        }
        throw new NoSuchElementException("No element");
    }

}
```

}

Comment: Queue means FIFO. This here is both a stack and a queue, both FIFO and FILO, with both `*First` and `*Last` methods.